# how to emulate a specific key press in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

Context: I want to make a minor mode where pressing `f` twice fast results in whatever the pressing of `(` should do at that time. This doesn't always mean just insertion of `(`. For example, in buffers where paredit mode or autopair mode is enabled, pressing of `(` usually results in insertion of `()`. In a paredit mode buffer, that sometimes results in wrapping the selected text: for example, if I select `a b` and press `(`, that should result in replacing the selection with `(a b)`.

For detection of `f` being pressed twice, I just need to take the logic in the short code in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/electric-dot-and-dash.el

So the only missing piece is a Lisp code snippet that tells Emacs "Trigger pressing of `(` now!"

The first thing that came to my mind was that the snippet should do

1. find the command bound to the key `(`
2. and then call call-interactively on that command.

but that breaks down if the auto pairing package (autopair or paredit or other similar package) binds `(` to a command that has a logic that looks up what key was used to call the command, or if the package simply relies on post-self-insert-hook or post-command-hook instead of binding `(`.

---

**update**

I've looked up Key Chord documentation and it turns out what I am trying to do with answers to this question has a simpler solution:

```
(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)

(defvar my-easy-open-paren-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (key-chord-define map ",." (kbd "("))
    map))
(define-minor-mode my-easy-open-paren-mode
  "In this mode, pressing . and , together is another way of pressing the open paren.")

(defvar my-easy-semicolon-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (key-chord-define map ";;" (kbd "C-e ;"))
    map))
(define-minor-mode my-easy-semicolon-mode
  "In this mode, pressing semicolon twice fast is another way of pressing C-e and semicolon.")

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'my-easy-open-paren-mode)

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-easy-semicolon-mode)
```

Triggering key press may still be useful in other contexts though.

Comment: Aren't you complicating the situation a bit?
Won't a key binding that inserts a pair of parens everywhere suffice?
I've had a pair of parens on `;-f` for years now and haven't touched `S-9` once.

Comment: @abo-abo, for this particular case, re-implementing the autopair feature for `(` of auto pairing and wrapping may be simpler. A more general case may involve making some key chord do whatever `(` does, and then making another key chord do whatever `)` does, and maybe some other things as well, as a minor mode which can then be enabled in only prog mode buffers.

Comment: IMO, such things as text insertion shouldn't be fiddled with too much. For instance,
I stopped using `autopair` since it was throwing errors while being used with slime.
And as @phils mentioned, binding `ff` with `key-chord` will cause you a world of annoyance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might appreciate the [Key Chord](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) library for binding functions to a double key-press. (I wouldn't recommend using `f` if you'll be writing in English, mind you; but YMMV.)

`post-self-insert-hook` would still run if the binding was `self-insert-command`. `post-command-hook` will run in any case, but if you're worried about it seeing an incorrect function and/or input event, you can manipulate those...

After looking up the binding, your function can set `this-command` to the function you're about to `call-interactively`, and `last-command-event` to the required key. e.g.:

```el
(defun my-fake-paren ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((command (key-binding "(")))
    (setq last-command-event ?\()
    (setq this-command command)
    (call-interactively command)))
```

Comment: Ha! Weird to see a near-identical solution to my answer appeared between the time I started and finished my response. What is the consequence of setting `this-command` in your function?

Comment: Tyler: Yes, I'd barely posted the edit when your answer appeared :) Setting `this-command` covers anything using `post-command-hook` to implement the behaviour -- when the hook function checks which command was performed, it will see the one it's expecting. If you're trying to fake a call to another command, it's quite a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Key Chord](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord) for this sort of thing, although the page you link appears to do the same thing. The trick is getting the call to `call-interactively` to work correctly. I wrapped it in a let that reset the variable `last-command-event`, such that `call-interactively` thinks it was a "(". This works for me in paredit and fundamental modes.

```
(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)

(defun my-paren-call ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((last-command-event ?\())
    (call-interactively (key-binding "("))))

(key-chord-define-global "ff" 'my-paren-call)
```